# Winform, TableLayoutPanel flickering on dynamic controls add/remove?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using CreateParams override in my winform application, to avoid flikering while i populatin g TableLayout panel with dynamic controls. The code is as follows,

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams CP = base.CreateParams;
            CP.ExStyle = CP.ExStyle | 0x02000000;
            return CP;
        }
    }
```

This causes my CPU usage gone to 30% plus, anyway to fix this? or any other way to avoid flickering?

Comment: I am simulating your code here with a MyButton : Button with CreateParems overrriden. Well with this method, i am getting Error creating window handle exception before launch of the window. I narrowed it down to this overriden method. Without this method, i can place my custom botton on form. Ill explore more on this method later.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i changed the value 0x02000000 here over a button. Upon changing the value to 0x00000020 it seemed to work. Or eve 0x00000040 also worked. But the original value what your using is causing the problem. So check that value again.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use those hex values like that because code is difficult to read and maintain.

as stated here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.createparams.exstyle.aspx

constants are defined in Windows.h installed with Windows SDK, you can copy those constant style definitions from that file to your source code and use the name instead of the value.